# confused on how to move forward with my code

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to fix something with column 2

[image: Column 2]

This is the code I'm using on column 2:

[image: The code]

```
=IF(MOD([@[charm_slot_no]],13)<> 0,
    ("Charm" & QUOTIENT([@[charm_slot_no]],13)+1 & "-" & MOD([@[charm_slot_no]],13)),
    ("Charm" & QUOTIENT([@[charm_slot_no]],13)+1 & "-" & 1))
```

`charm_slot_no` is the same as column 1, which is just numbers 1 through 96. If we take numbers 39 and 40 in that, for example, column 2 reflects 4.1 and 4.1. In reality, I want 39 to reflect 4.1 and 40 to reflect 4.2, and then should go on to 4.3, 4.4, etc. I know the problem with my code that is causing this issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it?

Sorry for the complicated code. There's probably much simpler ways to do this
This is what I would want my desired output to look like:
[![output][3m]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvGzC.png)

Comment: `39/10 + 0.2 = 4.1`?  TBH, your question is very confusing. Is your first screencap an example of the desired result? If yes, you need to explain the logic better

Comment: no, the first screencap is my column 2 which needs to be updated with the code. So suppose I am taking 39 in column 1 for my example, so the code in column 2 would read   false since MOD (39,13) = 0, and then it would read Charm 4-1. Likewise if I'm taking 40 from column 1 as another example, the code in column 2 would read true since MOD(40,13) != 0, and then it would read Charm 4-1. Now, I wanted 40 from column 1 to read Charm 4-2 instead, and then as u go up the column, it reads 4.3, 4.4, etc. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1743596/edit) with the desired result

Comment: I've edited it now. Sorry for the delay

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, maybe I don't understand why you use 13 if you want 12 values. And I don't understand why you inserted IF(). Perhaps you are looking for just `="Charm" & (QUOTIENT([@[charm_slot_no]]-3,12)+1) & "-" & (MOD([@[charm_slot_no]]-3,12)+1)` ? But then for values 0 and 1 you will get Charm1-10 and Charm1-11

Comment: Yeah you're right. I tried putting in your solution and its giving me Charm1-11 for column 1 no. 1 and Charm 1-12 for column 2 no. 2. I dont really understand why, but apart from that, its giving me the desired output and you simplified this by a lot for me. I will try to work with this.

Comment: your formula was correct, except instead of subtracting by 3, I subtracted by 1 and got desired output. Thank you so much!